# Problem with sound in Ubuntu 13.10 : sometimes is fine but sometimes is not work

Tags: partitioning, sound, mount

I have installed Ubuntu 13.10 beside Windows 8. When I shutdown Windows 8 in Fast Startup Mode (by default) and then run Ubuntu, Ubuntu cannot mount any NTFS partition and sound is working. But if I restart in Windows 8, partition will be mounted but sound is not working. I don't know why and how to fix it. Can anyone help me? Every advice is appreciate! Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Fast Startup is incompatible with dual-boot configurations. It basically turns a shutdown operation into a suspend-to-disk operation, which leaves disks in an inconsistent state. At best, Linux will ignore such partitions. At worst, data corruption can result. Thus, I strongly recommend that you disable Fast Startup in Windows, as described [here.](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html)

Note that the *Windows* Fast Startup feature is different from the *firmware's* feature with a similar name. Any "fast boot" or similarly-named firmware feature bypasses certain types of hardware setup. This is usually fine from a Linux perspective, although it can result in an inability to boot from an external medium like a USB flash drive. Thus, it may need to be disabled when installing Linux. Details vary greatly from one computer to another, though.